# Adding dynamic hyperlink with image source as text

Tags: html, jquery, jsp

I am trying to fetch the hyperlink with image source dynamically through Database and display it in the editor.js by AdminLTE,

```
 <a href="https://www.google.com/" title="Google - Home Page">
 <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Google - Home Page">                  
</a>
```

I want to display the entire hyperlink as `image source` as a `text` in my `editor` so that one can modify it as per requirement. I am adding the following as a `mailFooter` to my mail as per business logic please find the attached JSP and Jquery code for the following:

```
<input id="mailFooterContent" type="hidden"
name="myBean.filterMailFooterContent"
value="<s:property value="myBean.filterMailFooterContent"/>" />
    <div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h1 class="box-title">
            Modify Mail Footer
        </h1>
        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <button data-original-title="Collapse" class="btn btn-box-tool"
            data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="">
            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="box-body">
    <div id="editor2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#editor2').html($("#mailFooterContent").val());
        $(".Editor-editor").css("background-color", "#EEEEEE");
        $(".Editor-editor").css("pointer-events", "none");
        $(".Editor-editor").css(" overflow-y", "scroll");
        $(".Editor-editor").css("height", "150px");
        var mailFooterContent =$("#mailFooterContent").val();
        var displayMailFooter= "<p>" + mailFooterContent + "<p>";
        $('#editor2').html(displayMailFooter);
});
```

In my case, the value is stored inside the `editorBody` but is not displayed as the  tag gets into its ideal form of the hyperlink and the editor box is blank. Can someone please suggest or guide me on how I can disable the  and  and display it as text in the editor file?

If someone can help me out, I will be really grateful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi , open your element tabs inside browser and see html generated of that input see if it has value or not .

Comment: @Swati, it seems that the editor body has the correct value, but <a> overrides everything and the sole purpose of showing it as a text is not working.

Comment: please elaborate more .. which `a` tag ? overrides what ?

Comment: @Swati, the <a href> tag mentioned in my question comes as value of `myBean.filterMailFooterContent`, and later on I set it into editor2

Comment: Still not clear  .Your current jquery code simply get value i.e : `$("#mailFooterContent").val()` and add that inside your div does that part works or not ?